# Python list not sorting when called from inside a bash script

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I am trying to print a custom help message for a bash script. Inside the script, I call a function that then uses python to parse the script, find the functions and the function help string, and then print them. This all works. But, when I try to sort the list of tuples that contains the function name and help string, the sort seems to be ignored. Similar code works as expected in a pure python environment.

Edit: Just noticed I tried the sort two different ways. AFAIK either should have sorted the list, but neither worked.

Edit again: see the accepted answer below for code that actually works. I need to remember to reread my problem code in the morning ;)

```sh
SCRIPT_PATH=$(realpath $0)

function build() { ## builds source and wheel package
    echo "foo"
}

function aa() { ## foo
    echo "foo"
}

function release() { ## package and upload a release
    echo "foo"
}

function project:init:all() { ## Initialize a venv, update pip, wheels, and setuptools, and install both requirements files.
    echo "foo"
}

function venv:init() { ## makes a venv in the project directory
    echo "foo"
}

function print:help() {
    echo $SCRIPT_PATH
    python3 - << EOF
from pathlib import Path
from operator import itemgetter
import re
script_path = Path("$SCRIPT_PATH")
with open(script_path) as file:
    for line in file:
        match = re.match(r'^function\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\:-]*)\(\)\s*{\s*##\s*(.*)', line)
        matches = []
        if match is not None:
            target, help = match.groups()
            matches.append((target,help))
        #for help_line in sorted(matches,key=lambda func: func[1]):
        matches.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
        for help_line in matches:
            print("  {0:20}    {1}".format(target,help))

EOF
    
}
```

results in:

```
  build                   builds source and wheel package
  aa                      foo
  release                 package and upload a release
  project:init:all        Initialize a venv, update pip, wheels, and setuptools, and install both requirements files.
  venv:init               makes a venv in the project directory
```

but I expected:

```
  aa                      foo
  build                   builds source and wheel package
  project:init:all        Initialize a venv, update pip, wheels, and setuptools, and install both requirements files.
  release                 package and upload a release
  venv:init               makes a venv in the project directory
```

Comment: Not unless you see something here that i don't. But for the attempt to sort twice, I think I have used both sorted and sort correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all the functions, then sort and print :

```
function print:help() {
    echo $SCRIPT_PATH
    python3 - << EOF
from pathlib import Path
from operator import itemgetter
import re
script_path = Path("$SCRIPT_PATH")
with open(script_path) as file:
    functions = []
    for line in file:
        match = re.match(r'^function\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\:-]*)\(\)\s*{\s*##\s*(.*)', line)
        if match is not None:
            functions.append(match.groups())
    for target, help in sorted(functions):
        print("  {0:20}    {1}".format(target,help))
EOF
}
```

Comment: Gah! Rookie move! I was up way too late trying to get this one last thing to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Missed a  trailing } for the perfect copypaste fix. Thanks again.